# выборка данных из таблиц mysql c помощю bash

Tags: mysql, bash

как сделать выборку данных из mysql с помощю bash-скрипта, если соединение через ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

абсолютно точный ответ — никак: программа *bash* не умеет соединяться с *mysql*-сервером, отсылать ему запрос и получать от него ответ.

для этого нужно использовать как минимум ещё одну программу, являющуюся *mysql*-клиентом, и обычно называющуюся (внезапно) *mysql*. причём делается это фактически точно так же, как и при локальном запуске этой программы (только надо добавить `ssh пользователь@хост`). примерно так:

```
$ echo 'текст sql-запроса' | ssh пользователь@хост mysql
```

сравните с локальным вариантом:

```
$ echo 'текст sql-запроса' | mysql
```

если у вас на этом удалённом компьютере не настроен должным образом конфигурационный файл данной программы (по умолчанию — `~/.my.cnf`), то, ровно так же, как и при локальном обращении, придётся передать программе необходимые аргументы типа имени *mysql*-пользователя, его пароля и базы данных:

```
$ echo 'текст sql-запроса' | ssh пользователь@хост mysql -u mysql-пользователь -pпароль база-данных
```